# LinQ how to get only 1 result from join using geo distance

Tags: linq, inner-join

I have to following scenario:

A company can have many addresses, each address has a postcode.
customers search by postcode and the result should be all companies within a 10 mile radius.
A companies addresses can be in many different locations, i only want to return the 1 that is within the 10 mile radius.

I need a linq query that gets the companies and only the address they have in the 10 mile radius. I do not want their other addresses outside the radius.

here's what i have already but it returns all addresses, even the ones outside the radius:

```
var distanceMeters = distanceMiles * 1609.34d; //the distance

DbGeography geo = GetGeoLocationByPostcode(postalCode.Replace(" ", "")); //gets the geo for the query

//Attempt 1
return (from m in context.Company
        let ma = context.Addresses.OrderBy(ma2 => m.ID == ma2.CompanyId && ma2.Location.Distance(geo) <= distanceMeters)
orderby ma.Location.Distance(geo)
select m).Take(items).ToList();


//Attempt 2
return (from m in context.Company
             join ma in context.Addresses on m.ID equals ma.CompanyId 
             orderby ma.Location.Distance(geo)
             where ma.Location.Distance(geo) <= distanceMeters
             select m).Take(items).ToList();


//Attempt 3
return     (from m in context.Company
                from ma in context.Addresses.Where(o => o.CompanyId == m.ID && o.Location.Distance(geo) <= distanceMeters).ToList().Take(1)
                orderby ma.Location.Distance(geo)
                select m).Take(items).ToList();
```

So i have come to ask the experts as i'm an old fashioned SQL stored proc guy and as i'm learning linq with EF6 i keep coming up against queries that i could write simply in TSQL but this linq stuff is hard to get my head around, any help greatly appreciated. tks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var result = context.Adresses.Where(x => context.Company.Id = x.CompanyId && x.Location.Distance(geo) <= distanceMeters).ToList()
```

** This is untested, but I hope this gives you some idea ;)!

Answer (score 0):

lookUp is fast for relation 1-many:

```
var context_lookup_byID = context.Adresses.ToLookUp(p=>p.CompanyId);
var query = (from c in context.Company
            select new
            {
                Name = c.CompanyName,
                simpleAdress = context_lookup_byID[c.Id].Where(p=>p.Location.Distance(geo) <= distanceMeters).OrderBy(p=>p.Location.Distance(geo)).FirstOrDefault(null)
            }).Take(numbers);

foreach(var q in query)
{
     Console.Write(q.Name + "    ");
     bool notFound = q.simpleAdress == null;
     if(notFound)
           Console.Write("not found any address");
     else
           Console.Write("Nearest adress: " + q.simpleAdress.Adress);
}
```

I accept that data context.Company has property Name (string) and context.Adressess has property Adress (string)